# Slice on Django Model Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I try to run a query for paged results, like this
`Model.objects.all()[start: start+page_size]`.

I also want to know whether there are more pages to load, that is to say, I want to know whether `start+page_size < Model.objects.all().count().`

My question is, if I call `all()` twice here, whether Django executes the same query twice (one for slice operation`[]`, one for `count()`).

Another question is if I slice on a `Model.objects.all()` like this `Model.objects.all()[2:9]` whether Django fetch all data from DB and slice by python, or Django only fetch with SQL limit `limit 2 to 9`

Comment: btw, proper way for pagination in Django is here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/

Comment: Working link for pagination in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it makes two queries, but these are not the "same query" at all. One is `SELECT * FROM mymodel LIMIT <page_size> OFFSET <start>` and the other is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mymodel`.

If you want to avoid two queries, a simple fix is to ask for one more record than you actually need:

```
Model.objects.all()[start: start+page_size+1]
```

then you can iterate up to page_size, and show the Next button if the extra record is there.

Comment: If `result = Model.objects.all()[a: a+101]` and then slice on result `sliced = result[a: a+100]` or use len() `len(result)`, will Django make two queries?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated